# Eclipse: Debugging with Jetty and Tomcat not working

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, jetty

I'm trying to debug a project in Eclipse using Jetty or Tomcat, and it doesn't work (ie no breakpoints are ever activated).

I've got other projects that I can debug using both Jetty and Tomcat, but for some reason this project isn't honouring breakpoints.

Also, this is a spring mvc app, and it appears that any controller methods that have @PathVariable's in their method signature are causing errors to be thrown as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you may be choosing "Debug as | Run Jetty Run" or "Debug as | Run on Server", those options don't force Java to include debug information.

To ensure debug information is included, check the following:

In Eclipse:

- Go to "Preferences | Java | Compiler"
- Ensure all the checkboxes under "Classfile Generation" are checked.
- Clean and Rebuild your project (Project | Clean)

This is also the cause of the @PathVariable's not working problem (which is what helped me find out debug info wasn't being included). This is detailed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). Search for "As long as your code is not compiled without debugging information, Spring MVC will match the method argument name to the URI template variable name" to find the reference.